# Custom post type max num pages not working

Tags: wordpress

I am using custom post type in Wordpress and can not achieve rendering pagination. My problem is variable pages:

```
global $wp_query;
$pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
```

Variable pages returns following:  `Array ( [0] => ) 1`

I am trying to get number. What I am doing wrong?

I am using Advanced custom fields.

Comment: Hi, $pages should indeed be a float. Can you please provide more of your code so that we can see what's wrong please.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe1d219a59ec564d19fe/26112f69cbd57677f40c01672557c69e0484f29f I copied here my code and calling pagination with <?php bootstrap_pagination(); ?>

Comment: Could you please try setting `$paged` in your code? I don't see it defined. I think the usual method is:`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

Comment: I have that in my function bootstrap navigation which I am using for this. It is in gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/64597eaca8cfc4c3faa2 It is perfectly working with posts, but not with custom post type.